# How to connect to multiple datasources in Spring Boot, after the initialisation of the application context?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot

I want to initialize a data source in spring boot after the application context is initialized. There are several answers on the internet about how to setup multiple data sources, but each of them is done by somehow giving all the details in application properties before the application starts.
I found an article on baeldung about how to programmatically setup my data source, but this is not what I want.
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-configure-data-source-programmatic

I will explain,
I am dealing with several databases, lets take as an example that I am the owner of several branches of a school. Lets call the schools - school1, school2, school3.... and so on till school100.
The datasource link for each school is somewhat like this
jdbc:postgres:schoolserver01:21000/school01
jdbc:postgres:schoolserver02:21000/school02
jdbc:postgres:schoolserver03:21000/school03
.
.
.
.
jdbc:postgres:schoolserver100:21000/school100

In simpler words, what I mean is that I can construct a string to match the data source URL based on some programming logic.

The problem that I am dealing with is, I don't want to give the data source URLs of all the schools in the application props, instead I want to initialize the data source as and when the requirement arises by building an instance of the datasource for the required school.

Please guide me if it is possible, if yes, then how?

Comment: This might help https://github.com/bcssp10/multi-tenant

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you are trying to build is not practical and I doubt that you see a real world implementation on it. Spring boot when containerized should be disposable. One container should have only its dedicated database. I keep on writing more on this but it will help if you can read more on Microservice design.

Comment: this is a real world situation that I am asking about, just that i cannot go into the exact situation that is why I took this example, if you have a possible solution please help.

Comment: Not sure you already looked at this but if not then please give a try

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases